# Nested aggregation does not include relevant documents in it's bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I have a mapping like this (in YAML format):

```
order:
    mappings:
        number: ~
        createdAt:
            type: date
        customer:
            include_in_parent: true # this is needed so we can use `customer.firstName:<term here>` on the order index
            type: nested
            properties:
                id :
                    type : integer
                    index: not_analyzed
                firstName:
                    type: string
                    index: not_analyzed
```

Then I am trying to search for orders and have the relevant customers as an aggregation. So according to the elastic search docs, I should make a request that looks like this:

http://shopblender.dev:9200/mango/order/_search

```
 {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "customers": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "customer"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "customer_ids": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "customer.id"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I execute this search it will have empty aggregations (I have 30 orders indexed and they all have an inline customer object on it):

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 30,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
    ]
  },
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "timed_out": false,
  "aggregations": {
    "customers": {
      "doc_count": 30,
      "customer_ids": {
        "buckets": [
        ],
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "took": 1
}
```

Why can't I use the `terms` aggregation on a nested property? What am I missing here?

### UPDATE

This is the response of `GET /mango/order/_mapping`:

```
{
    "mango": {
        "mappings": {
            "order": {
                "_meta": {
                    "model": "Mango\\Component\\Core\\Model\\Order"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "createdAt": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    },
                    "customer": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "include_in_parent": true,
                        "properties": {
                            "email": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            },
                            "firstName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "lastName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "number": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "paymentState": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "shippingState": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "state": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query looks good, the only reason ES is giving zero buckets is because it is not able to find any `id` field. also confirm the mapping with `GET /mango/order/_mapping`.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 I do have an id field mapping on the customer. I have included the response of `GET /mango/order/_mapping` in my question. Do you see something weird?

Comment: `"type" : "nested"` is missing in mapping, thats the reason I guess

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Whoops, that was the wrong mapping. I fiddled around with it. I've updated my question, this is the mapping that should work in my understanding, I also tried using the `firstName` fields etc. I can't seem to get any results in the bucket.

Comment: I am using ES `1.7.4` btw, I will try `2.0` and see if that maybe helps.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Yep, that was the problem. Using ES `2.1` now and the issue goes away!

Comment: I dont think ES version is an issue, It worked for me on ES `1.7.2`. but I am glad It is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue with ES `1.7.4`, I've upgraded to ES `2.1` and my query did return the expected response!